# Why can't I load a Collada file using Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xml, xml-parsing, collada

I am building a game engine and would like to implement my own parser for Collada files which is in XML format.  I am trying to create a XMLParser to do this for me but for some reason when loading a .dae extension, nothing works.

Loading File Example:

```
//file = XMLParserDelegate
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: colladaFileName, withExtension: "dae") {
        if let parser = XMLParser.init(contentsOf: url) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
```

The funny thing is, all of this code gets executed.  It isn't until it calls the function "parseErrorOccurred" that I can see the error message which states "Document is empty"

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error){
    print(parseError) //result: Document is empty
}
```

HERE IS WHAT REALLY CONFUSES ME!

When I change the extension of my file to be .xml and change the function to be `"withExtension: "xml"` the code compliles just fine, there are no errors and I can see all of the files data.

My goal is to not have to change my .dae file formats to .xml everysingle time.  What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to read the contents of a `.dae` file by changing its type to `Data` in Xcode as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I don't know if this is a workaround that fits with your needs but I hope it helps

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you :)